# Add two items in an array in Lighting Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

Hi I have a JS helper in a Lightning component (aura) that is in the form of a list in a for loop. I would like to add the first and 2 items together to get the sum. What is the right notation for that? Here's an example of my code . Here I want oData.oppValues to equal the sum of points 0 and 1 in my array (the first two in the list) Note, below is just a code snippet of where i'm focusing on. I've tried a couple ways to add by adding i++ but it just doubled the value. thanks!

```
if (state === "SUCCESS") {
  component.set("v.opportunityValue", response.getReturnValue());
  var items = component.get("v.opportunityValue");

  var itemsList = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < items.items.length; i++) {
    var oData = {};

    if (items.items[i].oppCriteria.oppValues !== undefined) {
      oData.oppValues = items.items[i].oppCriteria.oppValues.oppValues / 100;
    } else {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is "assignment"; it overwrites whatever is in the variable. You want to use `+=` here.

```
var oData = { oppValues: 0};
oData.oppValues += items.items[i].oppCriteria.oppValues.oppValues / 100;
```

Comment: thanks for sharing! I tried that but am not getting the sum and still getting a list of items. I have it like this now

if(items.items[i].oppCriteria.oppValues !== undefined){
                    var ojData = {oppValues: 0};    
                    oData.oppValues  += items.items[i].oppCriteria.oppValues/100;

Comment: @DigitalWoman I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish? I don't have enough context to be too much more specific. You say you want to sum just the first two items, but I don't know what your data looks like, and what your end goal is. If you want to include more relevant information on what you're trying to do, and what your data looks like, I'll be happy to revise my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Today I am calling data from an endpoint via the apex controller. I have an Aura component where in the component I'm setting an Aura integration with this being originally a list to show  oppValues

in my helper function, my goal is to add all values in the oppValues datapoint together to sum it up. Maybe i shouldn't have said first two items, but really "all" of them .

Today in my UI, my list will look like 

oppValue = 0.1
oppValue  = 0.1 

I would like to have just one value like this that sums up that list of items
oppValue = 0.2

Comment: Nevermind- this is now working! the += did help a lot and i was able to figure out other pieces of the code that weren't working and fixed those